# Reading the UISlider maximum and minimum values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

Is there a way to read the maximum and minimum values of a UISlider that are stated in the attributes inspector of Interface Builder?
I want to use these values as the range for the X coordinates within a UIView and I'm not sure how to do this.

```
- (IBAction)sineXYPad:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)trigger {
    float sinepadHeight = sinexyview.bounds.size.height;
    float sinepadWidth = sinexyview.bounds.size.width;
    CGPoint location = [trigger locationInView:sinexyview];

    if ((location.y >= 0) && (location.y < sinepadHeight) && (location.x >= 0) && (location.x < sinepadWidth)) {
        float maxX = sinePSlider.maximumValue;
        float minX = sinePSlider.minimumValue;
        float sinePitchXY = (location.x > minX) && (location.x < maxX);
        sinePSlider.value = sinePitchXY;
        [PdBase sendFloat:sinePitchXY toReceiver:@"sine_pitch"];
    }
}
```

Here is my UI:

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want? You already access the min and max value of the slider using `float maxX = sinePSlider.maximumValue;` and `float minX = sinePSlider.minimumValue;`

Comment: @HAS Basically for these values to be the upper and lower values of the X coordinates of the UIView

Comment: I'm still not getting what you want to achieve. When you want the values to be the size of the `UIView` you can `self.slider.minimumValue = 0;` (a view cannot be smaller than 0) and `self.slider.maximumValue = self.view.bounds.size.width;`

Comment: @HAS [http://i36.tinypic.com/v78m13.png](http://i36.tinypic.com/v78m13.png) Sorry I realise I might not be being very clear. The slider values are min:35 and max:100 and I want those to be the range for the x coordinate value of the grey UIView.

Comment: So if the UIView has a width of 100 and a height of 50 you want the slider to have a `maximumValue` of 100?

Comment: @HAS Sorry, quite the opposite. I'd want the range of the x axis of be the range of the slider, if that's possible?

Comment: So what is the range of the x axis? Isn't it 0 to 100?

Comment: @HAS I'm not sure. How would I find that out?

Comment: @HAS I haven't edited it so I assume it is 0-100.

Comment: Then you should be able to use `self.slider.minimumValue = 0;` and `self.slider.maximumValue = self.view.bounds.size.width;`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[sinePSlider setMinimumValue:sinexyview.bounds.origin.x];
[sinePSlider setMaximumValue:sinexyview.bounds.size.width];
```